# Mutiple Objects authorization using pundit in one action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, pundit

In the code below i want authorize team and user.

1. By authorizing the team , i want to make sure the current_user is the admin of team
2. Second authorize is to make sure that the user being removed is not the admin(user) of team.

I assume you have basic knowledge of Pundit, a rails gem.
Is there a better way for doing the same.?How this code can be improved?

`def remove_user
   team = Team.find(params[:id])
   user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   authorize team
   authorize user
   ....
 end`

Comment: What do your associations/tables look like? Can a team have multiple admin users or just one?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out.I somehow solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the policy class you wrote add method to implement the logic

eg:

```
class PostPolicy
  -------
    other methods and declaration
  -------

  def initialize(current_user, user)
    @current_user = current_user
    @user = user
  end

  def remove_user?
    @current_user.admin? and @current_user != @user
  end
end
```

Comment: In my case I have mutiple teams and i want to authorize whether the current_user is admin of that team.Admin here refers to specific team.Not a general role.I hope you understand